# Identify self defined and declared functions

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm working with c++ in a classroom work and we were asked to identify in llvm code which functions were defined by the user and which ones only have name, arguments and data types available. These must be identify by a c++ code, and I couldn'f find any function in c++ which could help me to distinguish between this two type of functions. 
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Be much more specific. What is "LLVM code"? Try giving a complete example with all relevant data / pieces of code.

Comment: You want programmatically tell if header declaration of function has a definition attached to it or not?

Comment: The word for "*have name, arguments and data types available*" is *declared*. So your question can be simply "how to find declared but not defined functions".